# Troubleshooting a segmentation fault in Ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I just moved a working Ember-CLI project using Ember version 9 to version 11 and CLI from 0.1.15 to 0.2.2. After making all the necessary tweaking here and there though I now have an app that starts serving files but then immediately crashes with a `Segmentation fault: 11`. As far as I can see there are no logs anywhere and I'm at a loss on how to debug what is actually causing the fault.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to gain insight into a `segfault` is to install ddobson's debugging tool found on github at: https://github.com/ddopson/node-segfault-handler.

You can install this with **npm** with:

```
npm install segfault-handler
```

Then just add the following two lines to your `server/index.js` file:

```
var segfaultHandler = require('segfault-handler');
segfaultHandler.registerHandler();
```

This will produce a stack trace for your node_modules which are dipping into native code (which is likely why you're getting the *segfault*).

In my case above the problem clearly stem from SASS compilation:

```
PID 30497 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x71
0   segfault-handler.node               0x00000001040f890f _ZL16segfault_handleriP9__siginfoPv + 287
1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff90fd7f1a _sigtramp + 26
2   ???                                 0x000000010141c6a0 0x0 + 4316055200
3   binding.node                        0x00000001078a6fb3 _ZN4Sass6Parser16parse_expressionEv + 25
4   binding.node                        0x00000001078a6e11 _ZN4Sass6Parser14parse_relationEv + 25
5   binding.node                        0x00000001078a6bd1 _ZN4Sass6Parser17parse_conjunctionEv + 23
6   binding.node                        0x00000001078a6aef _ZN4Sass6Parser17parse_disjunctionEv + 23
7   binding.node                        0x00000001078a27b1 _ZN4Sass6Parser16parse_space_listEv + 23
8   binding.node                        0x00000001078a2ccd _ZN4Sass6Parser14parse_argumentEv + 349
9   binding.node                        0x00000001078a2a8a _ZN4Sass6Parser15parse_argumentsEv + 182
10  binding.node                        0x00000001078a8a30 _ZN4Sass6Parser19parse_function_callEv + 186
11  binding.node                        0x00000001078a7747 _ZN4Sass6Parser12parse_factorEv + 623
12  binding.node                        0x00000001078a714d _ZN4Sass6Parser10parse_termEv + 25
13  binding.node                        0x00000001078a6fb3 _ZN4Sass6Parser16parse_expressionEv + 25
14  binding.node                        0x00000001078a6e11 _ZN4Sass6Parser14parse_relationEv + 25
15  binding.node                        0x00000001078a6bd1 _ZN4Sass6Parser17parse_conjunctionEv + 23
16  binding.node                        0x00000001078a6aef _ZN4Sass6Parser17parse_disjunctionEv + 23
17  binding.node                        0x00000001078a27b1 _ZN4Sass6Parser16parse_space_listEv + 23
18  binding.node                        0x00000001078a2ccd _ZN4Sass6Parser14parse_argumentEv + 349
19  binding.node                        0x00000001078a2a8a _ZN4Sass6Parser15parse_argumentsEv + 182
20  binding.node                        0x000000010789de19 _ZN4Sass6Parser16parse_mixin_callEv + 211
21  binding.node                        0x00000001078a1949 _ZN4Sass6Parser11parse_blockEv + 1103
22  binding.node                        0x000000010789f864 _ZN4Sass6Parser13parse_rulesetE18Selector_Lookahead + 174
23  binding.node                        0x00000001078a1cfb _ZN4Sass6Parser11parse_blockEv + 2049
24  binding.node                        0x000000010789f864 _ZN4Sass6Parser13parse_rulesetE18Selector_Lookahead + 174
25  binding.node                        0x00000001078a1cfb _ZN4Sass6Parser11parse_blockEv + 2049
26  binding.node                        0x000000010789f864 _ZN4Sass6Parser13parse_rulesetE18Selector_Lookahead + 174
27  binding.node                        0x000000010789b98b _ZN4Sass6Parser5parseEv + 1651
28  binding.node                        0x00000001078402c1 _ZN4Sass7Context10parse_fileEv + 375
29  binding.node                        0x00000001078c1a69 _Z16sass_parse_blockP12Sass_ContextPN4Sass7ContextE + 162
30  binding.node                        0x00000001078c144c _Z20sass_compile_contextP12Sass_ContextN4Sass7Context4DataE + 343
31  binding.node                        0x00000001078c1715 sass_compile_file_context + 487
Abort trap: 6
```